# How to calculate the closest co-ordinates to a given point from a list of co-ordinates

Tags: java, android, algorithm, google-maps

Basically i have a users current location. i then have a list of co-ordinates.

How would i go about calculating the nearest set of co-ordinates from the list against the users current location. My application is written in java for hthe android platform

Comment: Do you know roughly how many co-ordinates you will have in your set? It might affect whether a brute force approach would work or if it would be far too slow

Comment: Hello there are 200 co-ordinates to test the current location against

Comment: For 200 coordinates, don't worry too much about it. Just test them all and it will most likely be faster and simpler than anything you could optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

```
Location location = new Location("");
location.setLatitude(lat);
location.setLongitude(lon);
```

check for distanceTo or distanceBetween methods.

Or you can manually calculate the distance among the coordinates and find the smallest distance for calculating distance you can refer following link http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.java.html

Answer (score 1):

If points on the list are rather uniformly distributed in the area, this should work:

Divide the area into quadrants of a certain size. Keep and update a list of points which reside in each quadrant.

Given a coordinate x, find the quadrant it belongs to, compute distances only for points in the same quadrant (if none there, add points from neighboring quadrants, until success), choose k closest points p_i.

Check if the circle c(center=x,radius=max(p_i-x)) crosses any quadrants that were not checked yet, and if it does, compute distances to points from those quadrants. Return the set of closest k points altogether.

Instead of selecting all quadrants in a circle c, you may want check closest quadrants inside c that contain points, until you find k closest points p_i so that all quadrants in c(x,max(p_i-x)) are empty or checked. 
Speed up the nearest quadrant search from O(n) to O(log n): you need to implement a tree-like structure: quadrants of 4 quadrants, etc. which tracks the number of points in each quadrant. When points move,  update it (O(log)). Anyway, for 200 points this is probably an overkill.

edit: instead of a "tree-like structure" just use hash table and an easy hash function, like: (x div 10^p, y div 10^p)

Answer (score 0):

There is a divide and conquer algorithm to find the closes pair of points in O(nlogn). Although it may be a but overkill for your data set size. More info on it [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http://www.cs.iupui.edu/~xkzou/teaching/CS580/Divide-and-conquer-closestPair.ppt&ei=I-ztTeThHsrRiALg-qWdBg&usg=AFQjCNGGr-O_jiQD3Gb57WMCk_uTDcFCOA&sig2=6qs9UyJdi7pitKJa-lH5Wg)